# What's in the box at the end of "Wonder"?

Tags: wonder

At the end of *Wonder*, August's parents are eating together, drinking a bit, etc.

During the course of the meal, his father gives his mother something in a box. She peeks inside and says that she'll use it later.

I didn't quite catch what it was, though - what was inside the box? Do we know?